# check if the user has admin rights for given fan page for Event Sync using Facebook Graph ApI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want Event Syncing on user's fan pages on their behalfs. For this first i confirmed that user has the admin rights for given page. 
I google but I can't figure out that how i checked that user has the admin rights for given page.

Any one has idea??

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an iframe application page the best way to do this is:

```
function parsePageSignedRequest() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      return $data;
    }
    return false;
}

function userIsAdmin() {
    if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
        return ($signed_request->page->admin) ;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here's some slightly lame code to do it.  Warning - it takes almost a second to retrieve the list of pages.

```
if ($session)
{
  # Find out if we're an admin
  $adminpages = $facebook->api(array(
                                      'method' => 'fql.query',
                                      'query' => "SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid='$uid'",
}

function isAdmin($thisid)
{
  global $adminpages;

  $pageadmin  = false;
  if ($adminpages)
  {
    foreach ($adminpages as $i => $page)
    {
      if ($page['page_id'] === $thisid)
      {
        $pageadmin = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return($pageadmin);
}
```